# How will the UK's economy be affected, if it will be a hard Brexit?

Tags: political-economy, united-kingdom

Will the outcome of Brexit have any positive impact on the UK market? Are there any available studies on this topic?

Comment: Welcome to the site.  However, the question as worded is rather vague since "hard Brexit" does not have a precise meaning.  All it indicates is less closely aligned on a spectrum of possible post-Brexit arrangements from more closely to less closely aligned with the EU, and as a consequence allowing the UK more freedom to try to negotiate its own agreements with non-EU countries.  There are various more precise questions that might be asked, eg about the consequences of a no-deal Brexit, or of a Brexit under which the UK would not be a member of a customs union with the EU.

Answer (score 1):

The UK government published "[Implications for Business and Trade of a No Deal Exit on 29 March 2019](https://assets.publishing.service.gov.uk/government/uploads/system/uploads/attachment_data/file/781768/Implications_for_Business_and_Trade_of_a_No_Deal_Exit_on_29_March_2019.pdf)" on Tuesday.